# Is there a CSS-only way of making dropdown menu items the same size as their parent?

Tags: html, css, navbar, dropdown

I've been tampering around in W3 Schools and so far I've gotten the desired effect, but the navbar now expands with the dropdown menu. Is there a better way of doing this that I'm missing? Apologies in advance for formatting, and thank you for your time.

EDIT: To hopefully clarify a bit further: [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ye6c.png)

**Link to the W3schools thing:** https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GD1ZCKC1TKED

**The code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <style>

body {
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }

.mainNav {
    background-color: #000;
    padding:12px 10px 0px 0px;
    float: right;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.mainNav a {
    color: #FFF;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.mainNav .icon {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 17px;    
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;

}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.mainNav a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;

}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .logo {
        max-width: 25%;
        height: auto;
        padding-top:10px;
        margin-bottom:-50px;
        display: block;
        margin: auto;
    }
    .mainNav{
        background-color: black;
        width:100%;
        font-size: 18px;
    }
    .mainNav a:not(:first-child), .dropdown .dropbtn {
        display: none;
    }
    .mainNav a.icon {
        float: right;
        display: block;
    }
    .mainNav.responsive {
        position: relative;
    }
    .mainNav.responsive .icon {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 15px;
    }
    .mainNav.responsive a {
        float: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .mainNav.responsive .dropdown {
        float: none;
        }
    .mainNav.responsive .dropdown-content {
        position: relative;
        }
    .mainNav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
    }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="mainNav" id="navID">

            <a href="#home" class="active">Temp1</a>

            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="dropbtn">Temp2 <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                </div>
            </div> 

            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="dropbtn">Temp3<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                </div>
            </div> 

            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="dropbtn">Temp4 <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                </div>
            </div> 

            <a href="#sources">Temp5</a>

            <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
        </div>

        <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var x = document.getElementById("navID");
            if (x.className === "mainNav") {
                x.className += " responsive";
            } else {
                x.className = "mainNav";
          }
        }
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: is this close to what youre looking for? https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown_navbar.asp

Comment: @ImmortalDude Close, the only difference though is that the dropdown items in would be the same size as the parent in the navbar (So referring to my code, the dropdown boxes of Link 1, 2, and 3, would be the same size as the Temp Box they came from). Thanks for helping.

Comment: I don't understand where is the problem, I tested your code and I see the code does what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your entire nav is expanding is due to the positioning of the item. You have the `.dropdown-content` set to `position: relative;` By changing this to `position: absolute;` it will fix the first issue.

However, now to get the width the same as the parent, there are a few ways to do this. The easiest would be to simply set a `width` property to the `dropdown-content` as well, so it is always the same. The only issue will be if you have longer dropdown content areas so that the words are cut off. If this is the case, you can use `min-width` instead. I have calculated the width to be `97.45px;` from the padding used on the `<button>` tag.

So all you will need to do is change your css of `.dropdown-content` to :

```
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  width: 97.45px;
}
```

or, like I said `min-width: 97.45px;` . This will keep it the same width as the parent while allowing options to expand with larger content.

If this isn't what you're looking for, please comment reply to this and I'd be happy to help. There's a few different ways to accomplish this. Purely setting a width might just be the most simple. Btw, welcome to Stack Overflow